# Shell script to extract all zip files in a directory and its sub directory, and copy the extracted files into another folder with same hierarchy

Tags: shell

I have some zip files like below.

```
./etk/test/etf_time_series_am_update.zip
./etk/test/etf_time_series_am_delete.zip
./etk/dir1/etf_time_series_am_update.zip
./etk/dir1/etf_time_series_am_delete.zip
./etk/dir1/dir2/etf_time_series_am_update.zip
./etk/dir1/dir2/etf_time_series_am_delete.zip
./etk/dir1/dir2/dir3/etf_time_series_am_update.zip
./etk/dir1/dir2/dir3/etf_time_series_am_delete.zip
```

I want these files to unzip and store into the another folder. like

```
./newf/test/etf_time_series_am_update.txt
./newf/test/etf_time_series_am_delete.txt
./newf/dir1/etf_time_series_am_update.txt
./newf/dir1/etf_time_series_am_delete.txt
./newf/dir1/dir2/etf_time_series_am_update.txt
./newf/dir1/dir2/etf_time_series_am_delete.txt
./newf/dir1/dir2/dir3/etf_time_series_am_update.txt
./newf/dir1/dir2/dir3/etf_time_series_am_delete.txt
```

I tried with the find command and able to unzip, but couldn't copy in the destination folder.

I tried to unzip by following command. but have no idea about copy into the destination folder.

```
find -name '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d "${1%.*}" "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: could you provide the peace of code you wrote, and what error you are facing, if you could paste error and code, it would helpful to answer question.

Comment: this might be asked without down-voting the question @@

Answer (score 0):

This might be works for you.

```
find . -name "*.zip" | while read filename; do unzip -o -d "`dirname "$filename" | sed -r 's/etk/newf/g'`" "$filename"; done;
```

You may also get better solution by referring following links.

- [Finding-multiple-files-recursively-renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/finding-multiple-files-recursively-and-renaming-in-linux)
- [Recursively unzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107995/how-do-you-recursively-unzip-archives-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories-from)

Comment: only getting unzipped. not able to copy the extracted fields into the folder newf

Comment: @ggupta, sorry, I tried the code, it is working only one level of recursion. this code may need to correct, to do for multiple levels of folder creation. I am new to shell script. I am also trying to find the solution. but if you are ok, instead of one line command, you can go for shell script which can do step by step.