# how to unzip all .zip files in folders and subfolders?

Tags: python, zip

I have a big folder `/myfolder/` that contains many different subfolders like:

- `/myfolder/aa/`
- `/myfolder/ab/`
- `/myfolder/ac/`
- `/myfolder/ad/`

and each of the subfolders contains many `zip` files. I would like to unzip all of them in the `myfolder` directly (all in the same place, that is)

How can I do that in `Python`?
Thanks!

Comment: that's a programming question bro. I can do it in Python if you like

Comment: So are you looking for a Python or an R solution? These multi-code-tag questions are always a bit "difficult" to digest. Better to stick to one language.

Comment: I wonder why you would comment on your on question with `that's a programming question bro. I can do it in Python if you like`, was it soliloquy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done in python, but a bash script might be more ideal.

```
from glob import glob
import zipfile

zfiles = glob('/myfolder/*/*.zip')
for zpath in zfiles:
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zpath, 'r')
    zip.extractall('/'+'/'.join(zpath.split('/')[0:-1])+'/')
    zip.close()
```

Comment: I like this one. pretty neat!

Answer (score 0):

I feel that a bash script might be better for you than a python script if you do this operation many times otherwise this question might be helpful to you.

[How do you recursively unzip archives in a directory and its subdirectories from the Unix command-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107995/how-do-you-recursively-unzip-archives-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories-from)

Comment: thanks but I want all of my output in the root folder, which is not what happens in the question you linked

Comment: You could simply add ```mv -v ~/new_directory/* ~/myfolder/``` then ```rm -rf ~/new_directory/``` afterwards. Which takes the contents from a output directory of the question I linked and moves it to where you want.

Comment: It's helpful if your answer includes actual code and context, not just a link to another answer. See [answer]