# unzip multiple zip files from within one biz zip file using Git Bash command line

Tags: bash, git-bash, unzip

I am new to this forum and new to working with Git Bash command line windows application. I have a task at hand that require to keep code in Git Hub. So start using Gitbash to transfer files to GitHub. I am having a problem to automate unzipping the code that i get from my Dev team. They send me a biz zip file with multiple zip files inside as a package / collection of zip files in a big zip file. e.g. the big zip file will contain: WebCode.zip SQL.zip SSIS.zip Reports.zip Release notes.docx

My Challenge is that, how can I unzip file: BigZipFIle.zip and its contents all in one shot: under GitBash command line prompt:

```
unzip -o BigZipFIle.zip
```

gives me folders:

```
WebCode.zip
SQL.zip
SSIS.zip
Reports.zip
```

what I actually want to do is to have a script that would:

unzip BigZipFIle.zip in the same folder c:\bigZipFile\
unzip all additional zipped folders:
go into each folder, pickup the unzipped files
transfer to GitHub respective folder, I have similar folder structure in github
I would really appreciate if some can help me create a script.

Thank you, Nad

Comment: hat I actually want to do is to have a script that would:

 1. unzip BigZipFIle.zip in the same folder c:\bigZipFile\
 2. unzip all additional zipped folders:
              <c:\bigZipFile\WebCode\>
              <c:\bigZipFile\SQL\>
              <c:\bigZipFile\SSIS\>
              <c:\bigZipFile\Reports\>
 3. go into each folder, pickup the unzipped files
 4. transfer to GitHub respective folder<s>, I have similar folder structure in github

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107995/how-do-you-recursively-unzip-archives-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories-from